# jquery access to checkbox in existing function

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I've inherited some code and it has some jquery form validation in it. I have to add a checkbox to the page and would like to use the existing code to validate it, but I'm not sure how to reference the checkbox in this function.

```
function initValidation() {
    $('.validate-form').each(function(){
        var form = $(this);
        var successFlag = true;
            // Added the input:checkbox
        var inputs = form.find('input:text, input:password, input:checkbox, textarea, select');

        function validateForm() {
            successFlag = true;

            inputs.each(checkField)

            if(!successFlag) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // check field
        function checkField(i, obj) {
            var currentObject = $(obj);
            var currentParent = currentObject.parents('div.row');

            // not empty fields
            if(currentObject.hasClass('required')) {
                setState(currentParent, currentObject, !currentObject.val().length)
            }            
        }
        // setState stuff
    })
}
```

I then set the checkbox to "class=required-checkbox" and tried adding

```
        if(currentObject.hasClass('required-checkbox')) {
            setState(currentParent, currentObject, currentObject.checked == FALSE);
        }
```

which didn't work, I also tried

```
        if(currentObject.hasClass('required-checkbox')) {
            setState(currentParent, currentObject, currentObject(0).checked == FALSE);
        }
```

and

```
        if(currentObject.hasClass('required-checkbox')) {
            setState(currentParent, currentObject, currentObject[0].checked == FALSE);
        }
```

Obviously none of those are right. Can someone tell me how I can be checking that checkbox? I just need to know if its been checked or not.

TIA!

Comment: Please start upvoting and accepting more answers or you will start noticing a serious deterioration in the quality and quantity of answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right these may help:

```
// If it's a checkbox and has the class "required"
if(currentObject.attr("type") == "checkbox" && currentObject.hasClass("required"))
```

Either

```
    // Returns true/false if it's checked or not.
    currentObject.is(":checked");
```

Or

```
    // Check it.
    currentObject.attr("checked", "checked");
```

Or

```
    // Uncheck it.
    currentObject.removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify it to...

```
if (currentObject.hasClass('required')) {
    setState(
            currentParent,
            currentObject, 
            currentObject.is(':checkbox') ? ! currentObject.prop('checked')
                                          : ! currentObject.val().length
            )
}
```

Then just add a `required` class to the checkbox `input` element.